# Graphhopper, osmdroid for osmdroid offline routing

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, graphhopper

I have been messing around for a while with osmdroid and osm bonus pack(amazing libs!), and have been pondering on the idea of offline routing and turn by turn navigation, now, I haven't tried anything yet, but something sounds very promising in throwing graphhopper in on the mix:

The official Wiki guide is as following:

- Download a raw map file(.osm, .osm.pbf, etc.).
- Run ./graphhopper.sh import map_file

Now, this is designed to work with MapsForge, and I haven't had the chance to check out the resulting .ghz file, containing the routing data for the map, BUT my question is this, could it be possible to use this routing data to build a PathOverlay object coming in OSM Bonus Pack  to actually draw routes of some kind?

I wonder if someone already tried something of this sort and has something to say about it, any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use graphhopper for every map you like. Just need to do similar overlay like we do with mapsforge.

Comment: Pardon the noobness, but could u provide a link to some code or tutorial where this is done, i've never done anything with MapsForge...

Comment: See the Android docs for GraphHopper

Answer (score 5):

Using Mapsforge in osmdroid: holy grail, never-ending story...

You can have a look at this (long) thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmdroid/gSieR9BF_z0

There is also this working experiment: http://www.salidasoftware.com/how-to-render-mapsforge-tiles-in-osmdroid/

Now, if you really NEED offline routing, your options are:

You leave osmdroid/OSMBonusPack and move to Graphhopper/Mapsforge, as suggested by Karussell => you will find docs on [Graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/) web site.

Or you can have a look at [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/). This is an app, not a lib. It has its own vector-based maps format (and toolset) and provides offline display and offline routing.

Or you can try to reach the holy grail, and merge Mapsforge, osmdroid, Graphhopper, and OSMBonusPack...

Comment: Merging Mapsforge, osmdroid, graphhopper and OsmBonusPack is not a difficult task, I have already build a working map application that uses Mapsforge (0.5) as tile renderer and OsmDroid (With OsmBonusPack) as the map wrapper.Using GraphHopper is pretty simple as well.

Comment: Please check my repository: [Using mapsforge, osmdroid and graphhopper altogether](https://github.com/Arman92/Mapsforge-OsmDroid-GraphHopper)

Answer (score 1):

The holy grail is possible, you can use osmdroid with vector maps and yes, GraphHopper works on Android, but be ready for OOM on low-end devices - GraphHopper requires a lot of memory.

[My sample project](https://github.com/lassana/offline-routing-sample/) should be a good point to start.